# MySQL stored procedure returns all rows, ignoring the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit confused as I couldn't find the reason why my simple stored procedure isn't working as intended. Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_GetEntriesTest`(
    in centerid int
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM `Entries` 
    WHERE `CenterId` = centerid;
END
```

The SP is supposed to select rows from Entries table where the given centerid parameter matches the CenterId column, but it keeps returning all rows in the table, even where CenterId does not match centerid.
I tried without enclosing the table and column names without ``, but same result. I really couldn't find what I am doing wrong, if anybody could shed some light I would be much grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working just fine.  You think that one of those `centerid`s magically refers to a column and the other to a parameter.  Nope.  They both refer to the column in the table.

So, give your variables distinctive names:

tended. Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_GetEntriesTest` (
    in in_centerid int
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Entries e
    WHERE e.CenterId = in_centerid;
END;
```

Comment: I added the in_ to the parameter and it works perfectly now! I didn't know SQL could ignore capitalization like this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for saving a life! I spent hours debugging this. Never give MySQL stored procedure input parameters the same name as table columns. Never!

Comment: Thanks a lot, spend hours for debugging this